# Find a specific letter in a word

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a hangman game, this is my progress. So the computer chooses a random word, prints out as many underscores as there are letters in the word. Now I need to check if a input letter matches any of the letters in the random word.
I've tried this so far.

```
var wordList = new Array("duck","cat","dog","carpet","pants","computer","book");

var randomWord = wordList[Math.floor(Math.random()* wordList.length)];
var underscore = function(randomWord) {
    for (i = 0; i < randomWord.length; i++) {
        document.write("_" + " " + " ");
    }
};

underscore(randomWord);

var guessLetter= prompt("Guess a letter");
var positions = function (randomWord, guessLetter){
    for (var i = 0; i < randomWord.length ; i++) {
    }
}
```

Now I am completely stuck, any help?

Comment: What has notepad++ have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The following suggestion would be what you are looking for, it will return a bool;

```
bool isItThere = randomWord.Contains('guessletter');
```

if you want the position of the characters see @guy777's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns all the positions matched by a letter in a word :

```
function checkLetterInWord(word, letter) {
    var positions = [];
    for(var i=0; i<word.length; i++) 
        if(word.charAt(i) == letter)
            positions.push(i);
    return positions;
}

var word2guess = "hangman";
var pos = checkLetterInWord(word2guess, "a");

for(var i=0; i<word2guess.length; i++) {
    if(pos.indexOf(i) === -1)
        document.write("_");
    else
        document.write(word2guess[i]);
}
```

Comment: how do I then use this to print out where in the word the letter is?

Comment: answer updated ! I give you a clue not the solution ;-)